# What's the difference between Entity.Attributes and Entity.FormattedValues?

Tags: c#, attributes, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm learning how to write custom workflows and am trying to figure out where and in which format all the values I need are stored. I have noticed that I can access `Entity` instance data in both the `Attributes` and `FormattedValues` properties. **How do I know when to use which one?**

I have noticed MSDN's remark *"Entity formatted values are only available on a retrieve operation, not on an update operation."*.

For testing I've made two foreach-blocks iterating through both collections. `Attributes` gives me 65 lines and `FormattedValues` gives me 39. I can see that, yes, the output from FormattedValues is indeed formatted. 
For example, where `Attributes` gives the output `"Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue"`, `FormattedValues` gives me a string with the actual value.

**Which values/attributes are generally excluded from the `FormattedValues` collection and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick check it'd appear that the difference between an  **attribute** and a **formatted value** is that the former to the actual value stored in the DB (or at least the value that **was** stored there at the occasion of fetching it) while the latter serves what's shown to the user.

I haven't used formatted values but until proven otherwise, I'd say that an entity's **attribute** will provide you with the **typed** value that the regarded field is based on (be that *int*, *DateTime* and such), whereas its **formatted value** is the rendered, stringified representation of that value (being dependent on e.g. what form you're referring to, what language etc.)

By that logic, I'd expect the set of **formatted values** to be a subset to the set of **attributes**. Also, it should be constituted of exclusively *String* typed values, while the counterpart is a member of [the type conversion table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328507%28v=crm.6%29.aspx).

An example of the difference I can think of is an option set called *picky* with the currently selected option named "*hazaa*" and the ID of *1234*. The below sample is written by heart so feel free to correct. It exemplifies the point, though: *plainValue* will be an integer equal to 1234, while *formattedValue* will be "*hazaa*".

```
int plainValue = (int)entity["picky"];
String formattedValue = (String)entity.FormattedValues["picky"];
```

I'd say that the attributive approach is more reliable as it'll render the actual values, while the alternative can lead to unexpected outcome. However, there's a certain convenience to it, I must add.

Personally, I'd recommend to look into the method [*GetAttributeValue<T>(String)*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg326129.aspx) or, as every cocky CRM developer would - have your own class with extension methods and use the method *Get<T>(T,String)* in there. That provides you with the sense of control and offers the best predictability and readability, IMAO.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but the formatted values are the values you will be able to see on the form. In that list you will be able to find money types with the $ symbol, or the labels of the option sets. A text field shouldn't be shown since is already human-readable.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmitchmilam/archive/2013/04/18/crm-sdk-nugget-entity-formattedvalues-property.aspx

Refer to this article to know a little bit more about it. I rareley using that attribute list since the data is in string format. I found it really useful to retrieve the OprionSet lables.